# Validating e-mail address input in C

Tags: beginner, c, validation, email

I have this little function to validate e-mail. It's a little piece of code to search major mistakes in e-mail input and it's part of a bigger program I have to complete as a school assignment. Is there a better way to do it in C?

I'd like to do it in regex but if I have understood correctly,  C under Windows doesn't support complex regex. And I use `scanf` to make testing this code simpler. Later, I replace it with another function that reads user input. Test is an array `test[40]` that is declared in `main`.

In addition there is a compiler warning about my `for` loop, that value computed is not used. It probably means `*ch`. I use it to end `for` loop when `*ch` reaches `'\0'`. I know I could use `while` loop. However, is there a solution to fix that or a workaround or a better solution using `for` loop? And I'd like to know, what would you do differently or what would you also check in addition to what I am checking in my code.

```
int test(char test[])
{
    int     i;
    char    *pos1, *pos2;
    char    *ch;

    puts("Enter email!");
    scanf("%39s", test);

    while (1) {
        for (i = 0, ch = test; *ch; *ch++) {
                if (*ch == '@') {
                    pos1 = ch;  // <-stores last @ address
                    i++;
                }
            }
            pos2 = ch;          // <-stores end address ("\0") of test

        /* If there is only one "@" */
        if (i == 1) {

            /* Pos1 - test <-a character must be before "@". Ch - pos1 <-Counts
             * backwards from the end of the string towards "@". A character
             * must be between "@" and "." */
            while (pos1 - test && ch - pos1 > 1) {

                /* From the end of string to "." has to be atleast 2 chars */
                if ((pos2 - ch) > 2 && *ch == '.') {
                    printf("pos2 - ch is %d and *ch is %c",pos2 - ch, *ch);
                    return 1;
                }
                ch--;
            }
        }
        puts("Email wrong! Enter again");
        scanf("%39s", test);
    } /* End while */

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: A 'little function' might not be sufficient here. See the Wikipedia article 'Email address', section 'Validation and verification' ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Validation_and_verification)) and RFC-s linked there. Some relevant examples and nice comments available in ['I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC'](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx/) at 'You've Been Haacked'.

Comment: @CiaPan- Thank you. That's why it is a "little function". It seems, that validating e-mail requires a lot of checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Formatting

> ```
> for (i = 0, ch = test; *ch; *ch++) {
>         if (*ch == '@') {
>             pos1 = ch;  // <-stores last @ address
>             i++;
>         }
>     }
>     pos2 = ch;
> ```

You have an extraneous level of indentation in there that throws out that block.

> ```
> int     i;
> char    *pos1, *pos2;
> char    *ch;
> ```

This is a weird indentation level, it doesn't match anything else and is unnecessary. It literally just complicates how you read it.

---

## Naming

- `int test(char test[])`:

Naming both your function and variables `test` is bad practice. How am I meant to tell as an outsider reading your code what it is that your code does.

> ```
> /* Pos1 - test <-a character must be before "@". Ch - pos1 <-Counts
>  * backwards from the end of the string towards "@". A character
>  * must be between "@" and "." */
> ```

If you feel the need to explain your code with comment blocks like this, you can probably improve your naming.

Name your variables as to what they are. For Example: `charactersAfterAt`.

---

## Duplicate Logic

> ```
> scanf("%39s", test);
> while(1){
>     // ...
>     scanf("%39s", test);
> }
> ```

You can reduce duplicate logic by declaring the scan inside the loop at the top.